# Binding request parameters with underscores in Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

Consider the following requirement: request parameters have to be bound to objects using Spring MVC 3.0. The request parameters contain underscores (e.g. `http://myurl:80/x?param_one=1&param_two=2`). These parameters should be bound to the following object:

```
class MyObject {
    private Integer paramOne;
    private Integer paramTwo;

    ...
}
```

How would you go about doing this?

**Important note:** consider that there may be a substantial amount of parameters and objects like this and that it's not considered good practice to define setter methods on the objects that include underscores.

Comment: I added an answer to this question, you can see below.  Did you end up finding any more elegant solution for this than what I provided? I'd love a better solution myself.

Answer (score 3):

Rajith's answer is for controller methods specifically, and doesn't address your question originally asking how to bind underscore parameters to an object.

The hacky solution I currently have in place is to accomplish what you are actually asking is to name my setters in this style:

```
public void setProject_ids(List<Long> project_ids) {
```

Note that RequestParam cannot be applied to methods, and it does not have an effect when applied to the argument of this setter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `@RequestMapping` attribute

```
@RequestParam(value = "param_One") String paramOne,@RequestParam(value = "param_two") String paramTwo
```

Add this into method signature

But for best practice its better to pass same variable name

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, keep in mind that at the bottom of the question I stated: *Also consider that there may be a substantial amount of parameters and objects like this*. `@RequestParam` is unfeasible in this case, as it would mean controller method signatures with over 20 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Nine-years-later... I cleaner solution is to use constructor injection and annotate it with `@ConstructorProperties`. This way you can keep the class immutable and use Java naming convention.

```
@Value
class MyObject {
  Integer paramOne;
  Integer paramTwo;

  @ConstructorProperties({"param_one", "param_two"})
  MyObject(Integer paramOne, Integer paramTwo) {
    this.paramOne = paramOne;
    this.paramTwo = paramTwo;
  }
```

Even if you have a very long list of fields, you can generate the constructor and only need to write the annotation.