# Binding request parameters (GET query) starting with underscore "_" to bean attributes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to handle requests like:

```
http://host/path?_param1=abc&_param2=xxx...
```

and bind them to bean, like:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

  @GetMapping("/path")
  public String endpoint(@Valid Data data)  {
    ...;
  }

  static public class Data {
    private int _param1;
    private String _param2;
    ...
    public int get_param1() {
      return _param1;
    }

    public void set_param1(int _param1) {
      this._param1 = _param1;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

The problem is that Spring ignores properties starting with underscore "_" or is unable to bind them to bean properly. I am just getting empty properties in data bean. Other properties are bound as expected.

Is there a way to handle that? I cannot change the URL and param names...

Comment: Have you tried using the `@JsonProperty` annotation, e.g. `@JsonProperty("_param1")`? https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html

Comment: It is not json. Those are plain GET query parameters...

Comment: Oops, didn't pay enough attention. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253371/binding-request-parameters-with-underscores-in-spring-mvc-3-0 ... They suggest using `@RequestParam`.

Comment: Have seen that question already. I need to bind to bean properties instead of every single param separated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It costed me some time but I figured out how to solve it. Spring binding has by default turned on mechanism to handle missing attribute values and to distinguish them from just not used attributes (i.e. http checkbox when is not checked does not send any param, but yet it was in form and this case should be treated as "false"/"null" as opposite to case when there was no such checkbox in form element). To do that every such attribute has redundant attribute prefixed with underscore ("checkboxField" has "_checkboxField" companion that is a hidden field and is always sent).
But processing such "companions" looks for field without underscore prefix and creates one with null value when it is not found.

To turn off the mechanism one must use @InitBinder method:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @InitBinder
    public void customizeBinding(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setFieldMarkerPrefix(null); //required to handle underscore prefixed fields ("_field")
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/items")
    String endpoint( @RequestParam("_param") String param ) {
        ... // param is populated with query string "_param"
    }
}
```